# String hash function returning unique hash for strings of equal length up to X length?

Tags: c#, hash

Is there a hash function that provides unique hashes for any string of equal length? Obviously for a finite hash size (32 or 64 bits, for example) this would have a limit on string length before that property would be lost.

Essentially, I'm trying to figure out if a string equality comparison optimization is possible.

```
public bool Equals(FancyString other) {
    // Reference and length equality checks ommitted...

    if (Length <= MagicUniqueHashMaxLength && HashCode == other.HashCode)
        return true; // since our hypothetical hash function is guaranteed to produce unique hashes up until X length

    // Full character comparison ommitted as well...
}
```

Does anyone know of a hash function with this property?

Comment: The resulting hash would need to be *as large as the string itself* to have that property.  Essentially, the only hash that will have that property is the hash that returns the thing being hashed exactly (or something that is functionally identical).  If you're just checking for equality, using a hash like this would *never* come out ahead, it will *always* be slower than just checking the strings themselves.

Comment: Each character can be 2 bytes for UTF-16 so you're looking at a max length of 2 characters or 4 of UTF-8 or only one for UTF-32 for a 32 bit integer hash code.  At best it's 8 for UTF-8 for a 64 bit hash code.

Comment: @juharr Double that for the 64 bit version (the question mentions both 32 and 64 bit hashes as examples), of course, but still not terribly useful.

Comment: @Servy note that I'm not calculating hash in `Equals`. The idea is that it's calculated only once per `FancyPantsString` and cached beside the reference to the string data.

I was thinking the constraint that strings of equal length need not share "hash space" with strings of any other length would make X slightly higher than N `char`s per 32/64-bit `int`.

Comment: @NickStrupat If you already have the computed hash the comparing the hash, instead of the string, will take exactly as long as comparing the strings themselves for equality, rather than it being longer.  It's still not actually a win.  As far as the length, technically strings in C# store the length of the string as an integer at the start, so your hash wouldn't need to have that, making each of your hashes 32 bits smaller than the strings they represent, but that's almost certainly not going to be a meaningful difference for you.

Comment: @Servy as far as I know, it's much cheaper to compare an `int` (length, also cached) and a `long` (theoretical hash in question) than it is to de-reference the `string` reference and then loop over all the `char`s. I'll admit I didn't measure that though. Either way, thank you for your input so far :)

Comment: @NickStrupat So you only ever have 2 character strings (4 if you store a long)?  If you need to do this for strings that are any longer, then you can't use an int or long, you need a byte array, at which point, I'd expect it to be exactly as much work as checking the strings.  If you know that you've only got 2 or 4 character strings, then storing the data in an int or long would effectively let you have a value type instead of a reference type for that data, so that would be where you'd come out ahead.